# eclipse build.gradle transitive dependencies

Tags: eclipse, configuration, gradle, dependencies

I am new to gradle, and have written the following configuration and dependency. When I compile using eclipse, it gives me errors because it is not importing the jars mentioned in "acceptanceTestCompile".
Am I missing anything? Any help appreciated. Don't want to move to NetBeans (which is picking up the dependencies without issue :))

```
sourceSets {
    acceptanceTest {
        compileClasspath += main.output + test.output
        runtimeClasspath += main.output + test.output
    }
}
configurations {
    acceptanceTestCompile.extendsFrom testCompile
    acceptanceTestRuntime.extendsFrom testRuntime
}
 dependencies {
    acceptanceTestCompile 'org.gebish:geb-spock:0.10.0', 
    'org.spockframework:spock-core:0.7-groovy-2.0',
    'org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:2.45.0',
    'org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-firefox-driver:2.43.1',
    'org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-ie-driver:2.43.1',
    'org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-support:2.43.1',
    'org.jfairy:jfairy:0.3.0' 
}
```

Thank you
Karthik

Comment: You may use the eclipse plugin in order to add the dependencies to the projects build path.

Comment: Hi, I did add the apply plugin: 'eclipse' line. That does not help...

Comment: You have to run the task 'eclipse' as well. Afterwards, the .project and .classpath files are generated...

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm tasked with fixing the same problem. In addition to extending testCompile and testRuntime we're making a call to `project.conf2ScopeMappings.addMapping` for each of our new configurations, but still no love.

Comment: Sorry Chuck. I did not apply Andreas' fix since soon after we moved to Intellij....